# How can I get the actual value from the result set rather than "System.Data.DataRow"?

Tags: vb.net, datarow

I have this code to get results from a table which contains the results of a query:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To categoryDT.Rows.Count-1
    Dim coName = New Label()
    coName.Text = categoryDT.Rows(i).ToString()
    formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(coName)
    Dim chk = New CheckBox()
    chk.ID = "chk." + i.ToString()
    formCustCatMaint.Controls.Add(chk)
Next
```

Unfortunately, though, what is added to the page is the correct number of checkboxes, but all adorned with the same value in their corresponding label. The label's text is not the value from the table, as desired, but "System.Data.DataRow".

What else is needed to assign the table rows' contents, not just the general type of the data?

Comment: `categoryDT.Rows(i).ToString()` should be `categoryDT.Rows(i)("columnName").ToString()`. Replace "columnName" with what ever your column name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use column name or index of the column to get the actual value from the datarow.

```
coName.Text = categoryDT.Rows(i)(1).ToString();
//here 1 is just a sample value. You need to put the zero based index of column whose value you want to display.
```